# Jazzy Scraping with R and without Selectors

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, ibm-jazz

I've been using `rvest` to scrape pages, and I am aware of the benefits of `selectorGadget`.  However, one page has data WITHOUT selectors. A snippet of the HTML is below.  The page [is here](https://www.jazzdisco.org/blue-note-records/catalog-4000-series/) .  I am trying to scrape the list of personnel on each jazz album listed. In the snippet of HTML below, the personnel data begins with **"Sonny Rollins, tenor sax..."** As you can see, that text is not surrounded by any CSS selectors. Any advice on scraping this out?

```
<h1>Blue Note Records Catalog: 4000 series</h1>
<div id="start-here"><!-- id="start-here" --></div>
<div id="catalog-data">
<h2>Modern Jazz 4000 series (12 inch LP)</h2>
<h3><a href="./album-index/#blp-4001" name="blp-4001">BLP 4001 &nbsp; Sonny         
Rollins - Newk's Time &nbsp; <i>1959</i></a></h3>
Sonny Rollins, tenor sax; Wynton Kelly, piano #1,2,4-6; Doug Watkins, bass     
#1,2,4-6; Philly Joe Jones, drums.
<div class="date">Van Gelder Studio, Hackensack, NJ, September 22, 
1957</div>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width="15%">1. tk.5<td>Tune Up
```

Etc...

Comment: Have you tried using xpath?: `'//*[@id="catalog-data"]/text()[3]'`

Comment: Use `html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="catalog-data"]/text()')` to get all matches, you can then remove elements with only `\n` and starts with `also issued`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked very well!  Do I use rvest to remove elements in the next step?

Comment: You can use the regular expression. I recommend you using `stringr` package and the function `str_detect()`.

Comment: I updated on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract using xpath and using regular expression to filter out elements. Following script should work.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

texts <- read_html("https://www.jazzdisco.org/blue-note-records/catalog-4000-series/") %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="catalog-data"]/text()') %>%
    html_text()

texts[!str_detect(texts,"(^\\n$)|(^\\n\\*\\*)")] # I just notcie this line doesn't clean up the string entirely, you can figure out better regex.
```

About splitting the string, you may try following code:

```
sample_str <- "\nIke Quebec, tenor sax; Sonny Clark, piano; Grant Green, guitar; Sam Jones, bass; Louis Hayes, drums.\n" 
str_trim(sample_str) %>%
    str_split(",")
```

returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Ike Quebec"              " tenor sax; Sonny Clark" " piano; Grant Green"     " guitar; Sam Jones"      " bass; Louis Hayes"      " drums."
```

Comment: This worked well. THANKS!  To parse the results, I used `df<-enframe(texts)` .  Now I'd like to put each name in a separate column. The standard string functions like `substring` and `grep` aren't doing the job.  Any further tips?